# Entity Framework Column Type for Base64 String

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, base64

I am using code first Entity Framework and four of my columns are a base64 representation of an image and are of type string. Initially, I was allowing EF to store these as the default nvarchar(max). I learned today that nvarchar(max) is twice the size of what the data actually is, when dealing with images this difference is tremendous.

I've tried to use varchar, but it appears the max length on that is 8000 which is too small for a base64 image. I've also tried text, but that does not appear to be a valid type.

Any suggestions for what may be a good type that will support the length of the data while maintaining a reasonable size?

Comment: The process of base64 encoding is fairly cheap (in terms of CPU), you might consider storing the data as binary and converting it in code to base64 for whomever needs to consume it in that form.

Comment: True, but the one very handy thing about storing a base64 string in a database is that you can retrieve the image via SQL and drop it into a converter online. This eliminates the need of a tool to retrieve the image.

Comment: "drop it into a converter online. This eliminates the need of a tool to retrieve the image" - what do you mean? What tool do you have in mind?

Comment: If I wanted to pull an image out of the database, I can just use sql server management studio and dump the base64 to my clipboard and then dump my clipboard into this site. 
http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/

Comment: Ok, for me it's a very rare use case. Think twice about this design, storing files as base64 text is not a good option.

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind that? I find it easier to work with as no conversion needs done before putting it in XML and it is fairly easy to consume across many platforms. I am not doubting that it may not be the best way to do it, but I would like to know the rationale.

Comment: You mentioned a concern about space, base64 encoding is 33% bigger than  binary. Whether this is "reasonable" or not is up to you.  By the way, it is not true that varchar is limited to 8000, varchar(max) will store up to 2GB.  You can use the following toselect a varbinary column as base64, should you need to do a paste somewhere:
"select blob from blobs
  for xml raw, binary base64"

Answer (score 1):

you could try `text` of `varchar(max)`

Comment: Yes, this worked, I was getting errors because I tried setting all of my columns to varchar(max), I guess you cannot use a varchar(max) as a primary key. Setting my image fields as varchar(max) seemed to do the trick.